# Cannot get FFMPEG in SNAP to convert videos to MP4

Tags: php, ffmpeg, paths

I recently installed FFMPEG with SNAP. For some reason, the regular ffmpeg install isn't working on this particular server. The file path that I have been using with my previous ffmpeg installation is /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i, as shown in this excerpt from the php file:

```
if ($ext != "mp4" || $ext != "MP4") {
    exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $uploaded_file ../user/$log_username/$db_file_name");
}
```

I am using RedHat. I typed the command, "which ffmpeg" and it showed the path as "/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/ffmpeg".

I also typed the command, "sudo ls -l /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/", and this was the output:

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Jul 11 04:18 ffmpeg -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Jul 11 04:18 ffmpeg.ffplay -> /usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Jul 11 04:18 ffmpeg.ffprobe -> /usr/bin/snap
```

I have tried all of these paths in my php code, but cannot convert videos to mp4. I'm very confused.

However, there is another alternative, if this can't be done. Is there a way to show the original file path, remotely, on the other server where the previous ffmpeg installation is located?

If someone could help me, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. Somehow, I finally got the traditional way of installing ffmpeg to work on the server in question. I know how I did it. What I don't know is why I was having so much trouble doing it. I guess you can say that my original question is a moot point.